# How to shuffle an array with n entries without generating range(n)

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

So, I'm looking at python and I have a large 2d numpy array of data, and I want to take m rows of this large data matrix. I've looked into random.sample, and numpy.random.shuffle and numpy.random.permutation, all of these work, but usually they return the whole permutation or at least generate the entire range(n). If I had a very large dataset, then doing something like

```
 data = numpy.random.uniform((n,100))
 myvec = data[random.sample(range(n),m),:]
```

will allocate a vector range(n) which blows up pretty fast. So i thought I could use xrange, which return a generator, but hey, you can't just get any element from an generator, that's not the way they work.

I tried it out, and it works.

```
 data = numpy.random.uniform((n,100))
 myvec = data[random.sample(xrange(n),m),:]
```

Any idea how?

UPDATE:

I can use

```
 samp = random.sample(range(n),10)
```

for n up to 100000000 before I get a memory error. If i use

```
 samp = random.sample(xrange(n),10)
```

on the other hand, I only start getting errors because of int converson to C, namely, the int gets too long to get converted to C, at around 1000000000. Sure it's only a factor of 10, but I'm curious. the xrange variant is also much faster.

Comment: The information should be kept somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean? xrange generates an object that dynamically generates elements when the __next__() function is called, if I'm not mistaken. So when you call it it doesn't keep the information anywhere.

Comment: Yes, but the [kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) of this information is very low, so a trivial algorithm suffice. the markov complexity of random sequence is as high as it gets.

Comment: I don't *know* you can't. I only think this way. But I'm sure you can get something that will look random, and or will be uniformly distributed.

Comment: Well, not really, the complexity is in the random number generator, that call will generate some overhead, but other than that, it's trivial to actually implement a sampler without replacement that won't keep the information anywhere and will do it relatively fast. Just take random ints between zero and the size of the vector and resample if you get a repeat. If you start getting close to the size of the list it'll be inefficient but otherwise.

Comment: so you will have to keep O(n) information.

Comment: Hmmm, I would think O(m) only, here's how: generate a random int between 0 and n. Before generating the next one, check if you already generated this one. If not, continue. Then, take the generator xrange(n), and step it to the desired ints in order. Since stepping through a generator is fast, it will be fast. So it might take O(n) to generate the permutation but you'll only require O(m) memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sample(n, m):
    d = set()
    while len(d) < m:
        d.add(randrange(n))
    return d

>>> sample(100000000000000000000000000000000000, 10)
set([5577049102993258248888250482046894L, 86044086231860190654588187118815513L, 2021737354726858669049814270580972L, 6253501639432326715043836478191628L, 5306460388221333758367322518700483L, 62195356583363524099133566314034473L, 376650426515181012918370326724858L, 80588135672357701239461833469588557L, 1978959860575617450893346333245569L, 41904683348442252013350548717573039L])
```

Note that simple `{randrange(n) for _ in range(m)}` will do the job with very high probability.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out xrange and iterators can be accessed by indexing, which is exactly what random.sample() uses. So that's how it works.

```
a = xrange(10)
print a[5] #this works.
```

Elazar's solution works just as well though.